# Xcode: Script not executed with "Input" and "Output" files in custom "Build phase"

Tags: xcode

I read [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-custom-scripts-during-a-build) article but I am still trying to understand the full power of the "Input files" and "Output files" when working with a custom "Build Phase" script.

Let's use a very simple example. Let say we have a script which will parse "FileA.swift" and update "FileB.swift", both files are at the root of the project, the script itself knows where to find those files by their path so running the script is enough on its own.
The question is what do I add to the "Input files" and the "Output files" to make this work. When I added those two the script does not execute once "FileA.swift" is changed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is what do I add to the "Input files" and the "Output files" to make this work.

Nothing. This script does not use input and output files. Make sure that all four categories (Input Files, Input File Lists, Output Files, Output File Lists) are *empty*.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I did not describe the question correctly. What if I want to make this script use use input and output files to take advantage of the incremental build execution of the script?

Comment: You can't do it for "this script". "This script" already knows how to do the work, as you yourself have said. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Ok I will ask a different question. I was looking for more of a general approach on how this should be done, but my question is misleading. Thank you.